# ionic - manually added js file is not being compiled

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, phaser-framework

I'm trying to use this lib in my Ionic 4 app:

https://github.com/jjcapellan/Phaser3-ScrollingCamera

As README says, I've download the script file and added to my HTML:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="/assets/scripts/scrollcam.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

So in my Scene I've added:

```
...
export class BlankSceneService extends Phaser.Scene {
    public myCamera = new ScrollingCamera(this);
    ...
```

But when I try to compile my Ionic 4 app, it stops on this error:

```
[ng] ERROR in src/app/services/blank-scene.service.ts(17,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ScrollingCamera'.
```

It looks like I need to `import` this class in scene script.

Is that correct? How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your script file to your `angular.json` in the script section

```
"scripts": [
  .....
  "/assets/scripts/scrollcam.min.js"
]
```

Now you have to declare `ScrollingCamera` and then use it:

```js
declare const ScrollingCamera: any;

export class BlankSceneService extends Phaser.Scene {
  public myCamera = new ScrollingCamera(this);
}
```